# Threshold voltage for townsend avalanche effect

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics

I have an assignment to estimate the minimal voltage required for an avalanche effect to occur. All data I am given is electron energy (`10eV`) and pressure of the surrounding gas (`10 hPa`).

I've used all my sources trying to figure out this one (books, internet), still no luck.

Comment: don't you need the ionization potential of particles?

Comment: I've literally provided all data I got.. If it is any help, this assignemnt is related to an excercise on Geiger counter. 

TBH, if I get any sort of relation/equation etc between the threshold voltage and the data I got. I probalby can figure something out on my own.

Comment: You need the mean free path times the field gradient to be greater than the ionisation energy. An electron has to be able to accelerate enough between collisions with gas molecules for its energy to become high enough to ionise a gas molecule.